# Spring Integration + filter + send a 400 bad request to REST controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a REST controller class which calls a message gateway and sends an Order to be processed by a Spring Integration flow:

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface OrderGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "orders.input")
    void processOrderRequest(Order order);

}
```

If the Order is valid, 2 events are sent to kafka. If the Order is not valid, a "rejected" event is sent to kafka and a 400 Bad request should be sent back to the REST controller class so that the user knows that there is something wrong with the request.

I've been able to make this flow work except for the part to send back a 400 Bad request to the controller.

The following is what I have so far which is successfully sending the events to kafka:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow orders(KafkaTemplate<?, ?> kafkaTemplate) {
    return f -> f
            .<Order> filter(request -> orderValidator.isValid(request), fs -> fs.discardFlow(
                    df -> df
                            .transform(orderRejectedEventTransformer)
                            .handle( m -> Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate).messageKey(this.properties.getMessageKey()) )
            ))
            .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
                    .subscribe(fl -> fl
                            .transform(orderReceivedEventTransformer)
                            .handle(  Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate).messageKey(this.properties.getMessageKey()) )
                    )
                    .subscribe(fl -> fl
                            .transform(orderSuccessfulEventTransformer)
                            .handle( Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate).messageKey(this.properties.getMessageKey()) )
                    )
            );
}
```

I think I have to throw an exception somewhere, but I'm completely lost as to how to send a bad request response.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring MVC comes with some default configuration and one part of that is an exception handling. It looks like this in the `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`:

```
/**
 * A method available to subclasses for adding default
 * {@link HandlerExceptionResolver HandlerExceptionResolvers}.
 * <p>Adds the following exception resolvers:
 * <ul>
 * <li>{@link ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver} for handling exceptions through
 * {@link org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler} methods.
 * <li>{@link ResponseStatusExceptionResolver} for exceptions annotated with
 * {@link org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus}.
 * <li>{@link DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver} for resolving known Spring exception types
 * </ul>
 */
protected final void addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(List<HandlerExceptionResolver> exceptionResolvers,
        ContentNegotiationManager mvcContentNegotiationManager) {
```

You may not have any `@ExceptionHandler`, you also may not throw a custom exception with the `@ResponseStatus`, but `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` may do the trick for you.

To send `400 Bad request` back to the client, you need throw `HttpMessageNotReadableException`.

You have to throw such an exception in the parallel with the `.handle()` to Kafka when rejected. I mean a `publishSubscribeChannel()` should fit here well.

Answer (score 0):

Artem,

When you say to throw an exception in parallel with the .handle, do you mean something like this:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow orders(KafkaTemplate<?, ?> kafkaTemplate) {
    return f -> f
            .<Order> filter(request -> orderValidator.isValid(request), fs -> fs.discardFlow(
                    df -> df
                    .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
                            .subscribe(fl -> fl
                                    .transform(orderRejectedEventTransformer)
                                    .handle(  Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate).messageKey(this.properties.getMessageKey()) )
                            )
                            .subscribe(fl -> fl
                                    .handle(  handleException() )
                            )
                    )
            ))
            .publishSubscribeChannel(s -> s
                    .subscribe(fl -> fl
                            .transform(orderReceivedEventTransformer)
                            .handle(  Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate).messageKey(this.properties.getMessageKey()) )
                    )
                    .subscribe(fl -> fl
                            .transform(orderSuccessfulEventTransformer)
                            .handle( Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate).messageKey(this.properties.getMessageKey()) )
                    )
            );
}

    public void handleException() throws Exception {
        throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException("bad request");
    }
```

I was able to make it work, I mean to send the 400 Bad request, but I did have to do something like this

```
.handle(  exceptionService ) //injected bean

@Component
public class ExceptionService {
    public void handleException() throws Exception {
        throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException("bad request");
    }
}
```

I was not able to call handleException() method directly in the .handle method since it's throwing an exception. Not sure how to handle it, so I had to create that component, but don't like it pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if having a replyChannel on the message gateway is the way to send back a response from the Spring Integration flow to the rest controller.